# There is a default timeout with q.allSettled?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a NodeJS app who is fetch lot of information from differents API.

During the biggest fetching, i have some issues with my promises.

I guess I launch too many requests and too fastly ...

```js
 var promises = [];
 list_consumptions.forEach(function (item)
 {
   item.consumptions.forEach(function (data)
   {
    promises.push(getDetails(item.line, data));
   });
 });
```

In the getDetails()

```js
function getDetails(line, item)
{
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  var result = [];
    ovh.request('GET', '/telephony/*******/service/' + line + '/voiceConsumption/' + item, function (err, fetched_data)
    {
      if (!err)
      {
        result = {
          'line': line,
          'consumption_id': item,
          'type': fetched_data.wayType,
          'calling': fetched_data.calling,
          'called': fetched_data.called,
          'plan_type': fetched_data.planType,
          'destination_type': fetched_data.destinationType,
          'date': fetched_data.creationDatetime,
          'duration': fetched_data.duration,
          'price': fetched_data.priceWithoutTax
        };
        // console.log("RESULT: ",result);
        deferred.resolve(result);
      }
      else
      {
        deferred.reject(err);
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

After the loop :

```js
Q.allSettled(promises).done(function(final_result)
  {
    final_result.forEach(function (promise_fetch){
      if (promise_fetch.state != 'fulfilled')
      {
        console.log("ERREUR Merge");
      }
      else
      {
        all_consumptions.push(promise_fetch.value);
      }
      deferred.resolve(all_consumptions);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  });
```

With this code, i've got exclusively log error : 400

I'd try to slow down my loop with some setTimeOut, in this case, the fetch succeed but my q.allSettled is jumped... I'm really lost...

Any ideas to improve my promises handles / loop handles ?
I'm pretty sure that you already know, but it's my first week of JS... and nodeJS.

Thanks a lot for your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a promise-loop, like this:

```
function pwhile(condition, body) {
  var done = Q.defer();

  function loop() {
    if (!condition())
      return done.resolve();
    Q.when(body(), loop, done.reject);
  }

  Q.nextTick(loop);

  return done.promise;
}
```

And then, your code would be:

```
list_consumptions.forEach(function (item) {
  var i = 0;
  pwhile(function() { return i < item.consumptions.length; }, function() {
    i++;
    return getDetails(item.line, data)
      .then(function(res) {
        all_consumptions.push(res);
      })
      .catch(function(reason) {
        console.log("ERREUR Merge");
      });
  }).then(function() {
    // do something with all_consumptions here
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, the resquests succeed now :) But the loop forEach do not return a promise, so the ".then" after it, is executed before any push on all_consumption...

Comment: @Leclerc it was a typo, the `then` method should be placed right after the `pwhile` execution, e.g `pwhile().then()`. I've fixed my answer. Btw, if it was useful for you, please upvote it by clicking on the arrow and Mark it as the accepted by clicking on the `V` right below it. Thanks! :)